# Collect accounts followed by an user efficiently

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I am using this function to collect the usernames of the accounts followed by a user. The problem is that is very unefficient because it collects the whole user object. Is there a way to collect only the username or to do it more efficiently?

```
def collect_followed_by_user(api,target_user):
    all_followed = []   
    ids = []
    try:  
        for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_ids, screen_name=target_user).pages():
            ids.extend(page) 
        for identifier in ids:
            name = api.get_user(identifier).screen_name
            all_followed.append(name)
    except:
        exit(1)

    return all_followed
```

The function uses the Twitter API with tweepy.

Comment: Are you asking if the Tweepy library has a way of only retrieving the username from the Twitter API, instead of retrieving the whole user object? Going by the API documentation http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html, that doesn't appear to be the case, but it's not really a programming question to begin with. If you have questions about the features of a specific library or API, the question is best directed at their community or support.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, tweepy is based on Twitter API (without surprise!). As it is in code of tweepy get_user() used this reference to [get user](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show) of Twitter API.

It is not possible to get only names or increase efficiency with tweepy. But you could try [users/lookup](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-lookup) directly with Twitter API or find the same method in another lib.